# What is the difference between copy and deep copy in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand the difference between `copy()` and `deepcopy()` in Julia. Based on what I read in [the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.copy) it seems like `deepcopy()` copies the values and then makes a while new object un-related to the original object that I copied from. That part makes sense. I am more so confused about the relationship between the following objects:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> b = copy(a)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a == b
true

julia> isequal(a,b)
true
```

Maybe this is just a bad example I chose above but I don't how deep copying would provide a different result (maybe it won't in my simple example but is there a tried and true example that highlights the difference between deep and regular copy?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The important difference is that `deepcopy` is recursive while `copy` isn't:

```
julia> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

julia> b = copy(a);

julia> c = deepcopy(a);

julia> a[1][1] = 11
11

julia> a
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [11, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]

julia> b
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [11, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]

julia> c
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

To complement @pfitzseb [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017711/2442087), note that both [`==`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.:==) and [`isequal`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.isequal) only check that the corresponding elements of the arrays are equal in some sense, which is still true when copying `a` to `b`, even though the two objects are distinct in memory.

The [`===`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.:===) operator, instead, checks whether two objects are indistinguishable for any program.  This operator is sometimes called *egality* in Julia's jargon:

```
julia> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

julia> b = copy(a);

julia> a == b
true

julia> isequal(a, b)
true

julia> a === b
false
```